# Storing context in an adapter when it seems unnecessary to do so

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-context

I was looking at examples on how to use an adapter to handle live query here: [ToDoLite-Android LiveQueryAdapter](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/couchbase/todolite/util/LiveQueryAdapter.java), and I have a question regarding this part:

```java
private LiveQuery query;
private QueryEnumerator enumerator;
private Context context;

public LiveQueryAdapter(Context context, LiveQuery query) {
    this.context = context;
    this.query = query;

    query.addChangeListener(new LiveQuery.ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final LiveQuery.ChangeEvent event) {
            ((Activity) LiveQueryAdapter.this.context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    enumerator = event.getRows();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    query.start();
}
```

In several activities, he/she used adapters that extend LiveQueryAdapter. The adapters were initialized by passing in an activity and a live query.

Examples [here](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-Android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/couchbase/todolite):

```java
// 'this' are all activities, I think
mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, query.toLiveQuery());
mAdapter = new UserAdapter(this, getQuery().toLiveQuery());
mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(this, query.toLiveQuery());
```

So here's my question: Why do we need to store that context in the contructor?
Does it have something to do with runOnUiThread? Why not just do this:

```java
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(...
```

I don't see the stored context variable used anywhere else but in that one line, so why bother saving it?

I know the context can probably be used in getView(), but his/her code uses parent.getContext() instead. Also, in my code I am using RecyclerView instead of ListView so I don't even have getView() method I don't think.

Comment: Yes, you can do as you told. I think this is just for others to understand what is happening in the code, but makes no difference. But maybe inside of the function you will need to use variable with 'final' signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context allows the adapter to reference the activity and application state. The Adapter needs context update the activity and access any UI components

Comment: Right, and I understand that, but isn't that what ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(... is doing?

Comment: so your question is why bother saving it? Mine is why are you worried about it? It would work fine if you used the context variable directly as well.